# Extracting codes from strings in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a column which contains codes and descriptions and need to split them.

Multiple codes may or may not reside in the field.

Eg;

```
"CSxxxxx description text here"

"WSxxxxx description text here"

"CSxxxxx, WSxxxxx, CSxxxxx description text here"
```

If there are multiple codes, then the description should be repeated, so the output for row 3 above would be 3 lines inserted into a secondary table.

The codes, for the moment, would always be in the format of:

```
FixedLetter-FixedLetter-Number-Number-Number-Number-Number
```

OR

```
FixedLetter-FixedLetter-Number-Number-Number-Number
```

I can write the regex to identify the first couple, but i'm not familiar with cutting this from the string and inserting to another table?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Do you have a table of codes that you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, there are 3 current variants at the moment but needs to be scale-able as expect more. Work with CSxxxxx, WSxxxxx and CLxxxx for the moment where x is a number 0-9. So a regex pattern for cs/ws would be ((?:C|W)S)[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]

Comment: SQL Server does not support regex in TSQL. You could write a CLR function that does this and uses regex though. This will be simpler and better performing than a SQL solution.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not so hot with regex nor CLR functions - just knew roughly want i needed to achieve. I don't have to worry too much about performance, its not got much to parse and will be part of an overnight maintenance job on a non-production environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is with a CROSS APPLY in concert with a little XML as the parser (assuming not 2016)

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (ID int,[SomeCol] varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'CS12345 description text here for id 1')
,(2,'WS67890 description text here for id 2')
,(3,'CS23456, WS34567, CS45678 description text here for id 3')
,(4,'No Codes Just a Desc')

 ;with cte as (
     Select A.ID
          ,B.*
     From @YourTable A
     Cross Apply (
                    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(A.SomeCol,' ','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                 ) B
 )
Select ID
      ,Code  = replace(RetVal,',','')
      ,Descr = Stuff((Select ' ' +RetVal From cte Where A.ID=ID and RetVal Not Like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' Order By RetSeq  For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
 From  cte A
 Where RetVal Like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
Union All
Select ID
      ,Code = ''
      ,SomeCol
 From @YourTable
 Where SomeCol not like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Code      Descr
1   CS12345   description text here for id 1
2   WS67890   description text here for id 2
3   CS23456   description text here for id 3
3   WS34567   description text here for id 3
3   CS45678   description text here for id 3
4             No Codes Just a Desc
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149902/discussion-between-dave-leech-and-john-cappelletti).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of doing this "easily" is by splitting the string.  SQL Server 2016 has a string split function.  You can find one on the web by Googling "SQL Server split".

Then it would be something like this:

```
select t.*, c.code
from t outer apply
     (select s.code
      from dbo.split(textcol, ' ')) s(code)
      where replace(code, ',', '') like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' or
            replace(code, ',', '') like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
     ) c(code);
```

Note that this should work for the examples in your question.  It might not work on all your data.  Text is never clean.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to play ball with the split function i found online, not sure if its your code or an incompatibility though at this point - probably the latter!